# Pandas dataframe to Html ValueError: Styles supplied as string must follow CSS rule formats

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

I'm trying to write a Pandas data frame to HTML format (Pandas 1.5.3) and getting the following error. The code however runs fine in PD version 0.25.1.

This is a small dataframe which I uploaded in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/MGnwCvMk)

```py
import pandas as pd


url_raw = "https://pastebin.com/raw/MGnwCvMk"
re_df = pd.read_csv(url_raw, sep="\t", na_filter=False)

columns_with_color_dictionary = {
    "Seq": "#FFFFFF",
    "Cov": "#FFFFFF",
    "CTer": "#FFFFFF",
    "NTer": "#FFFFFF",
    "B13": "#fc9863",
    "F0": "#fdca93",
    "F1": "#fdbb85",
    "F3": "#fdbd86",
    "F2": "#fdbb85",
    "Y73": "#fda671",
    "Y59": "#f06749",
    "Y58": "#840000",
    "Y45": "#fdd6a3",
    "Y37": "#feeacc",
    "Y26": "#fdb67f",
    "Y24": "#fdaf79",
    "Y13": "#fca36e",
}

def f_color(dat,c='red'):
    return [f'background-color: {c}' if v=='1' else '#FFFFFF' for v in dat]
        
style = re_df.style
style = style.set_properties(width="25px")

for column, color in columns_with_color_dictionary.items():
    style = style.apply(f_color, axis=0, subset=column, c=color)
    
with open("MyTest.html", 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(style.render())
```

I've tried style.to_html(), but I'm getting the following error code (PD version 0.25.1 works fine):

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10844\4235473097.py:31: FutureWarning: this method is deprecated in favour of `Styler.to_html()`
  fh.write(style.render())
Traceback (most recent call last):
    
  File C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style_render.py:1873 in maybe_convert_css_to_tuples
        return [
    
  File C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style_render.py:1874 in <listcomp>
        (x.split(":")[0].strip(), x.split(":")[1].strip())
    
IndexError: list index out of range
    
    
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
Traceback (most recent call last):
    
  Cell In[76], line 31
    fh.write(style.render())
    
  File C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py:457 in render
    return self._render_html(sparse_index, sparse_columns, **kwargs)
    
  File C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style_render.py:206 in _render_html
    d = self._render(sparse_index, sparse_columns, max_rows, max_cols, "&nbsp;")
    
  File C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style_render.py:163 in _render
    self._compute()
    
  File C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style_render.py:258 in _compute
    r = func(self)(*args, **kwargs)
    
  File C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py:1762 in _apply
    self._update_ctx(result)
    
  File C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py:1585 in _update_ctx
    css_list = maybe_convert_css_to_tuples(c)
    
  File C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style_render.py:1879 in maybe_convert_css_to_tuples
    raise ValueError(
    
ValueError: Styles supplied as string must follow CSS rule formats, for example 'attr: val;'. '#FFFFFF' was given.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that the `else` branch of your list comprehension is incorrect.

Try replacing:

- `[f'background-color: {c}' if v=='1' else '#FFFFFF' for v in dat]`

With:

- `[f"background-color: {c}" if v == "1" else f"background-color: #FFFFFF"  for v in dat]`

Then:

```py
style.to_html("./MyTest.html")  # instead of with open(...) statement
```

[image]